# Going mad with \wrapfigure and \itemize conflict

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize, wrapfigure

I am trying to insert an image floating in a bullet point list, in beamer.
Sadly the result is that the image is put in a new frame, following the one where I insert the code.
Moreover, I am not able to moove the image: any of \wrapfigure{R},  \wrapfigure{T}... and so on gives the same result, whereas I would expect my image to be put Right, Top and so on.
Here's the code I wrote

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}
\usetheme{UCBerkeley}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Simplicial Subdivisions}

\begin{itemize}
\item Let $T=\sigma(x^0,...,x^n)$ be an n-simplex. A \textbf{simplicial subdivision} of T is a collection of (sub-) simplexes $\{T_i: i\in I\}$ such that $\bigcup_i T_i=\ \Bar{T}$ and $\forall i,j\ \Bar{T_j}\cap\Bar{T_j}$ either equals $\emptyset$ or the closure of a common face $\Bar{F_{ij}}$.
\begin{wrapfigure}{h}{0.25\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Subdivision.PNG}
\end{wrapfigure}
\pause
\item An important subdivision is the equilateral one 
\pause
\item The \textbf{mesh of a subdivision} is the diameter of its largest element
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: wrapfig does document that it can not be used near lists such as `itemize` also, it does not have an `{h}` argument. It would be easier to help if your example was a complete document that could be tested to see the problem (you could use `example-image`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank for the advice, I edited the question so the code should be testable

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Anyway I don't really see your point: obviously my document is running and I forgot that line, my problem does not depend on that

Comment: The point is you are giving us something to to test that does not compile, thus others probably will not devote time for your question

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta the fact that you have a document running does not help anyone debug anything, you are asking people to debug the code that you posted and if it does not produce the problem you described that makes it hard for anyone to help you. Also `! LaTeX Error: File 'beamerthemeUCBerkeley.sty' not found`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that using the plain TeX macro package `insbox` and `enumitem` (to change the right margin of the list), it works. Not sure there are no side-effects, though.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Simplicial Subdivisions}

\InsertBoxR{1}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Subdivision.PNG}}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\blacktriangleright$, rightmargin=0.27\linewidth]
\item Let $T=\sigma(x^0,...,x^n)$ be an n-simplex. A \textbf{simplicial subdivision} of T is a collection of (sub-) simplexes $\{T_i: i\in I\}$ such that $\bigcup_i T_i=\ \Bar{T}$ and $\forall i,j\ \Bar{T_j}\cap\Bar{T_j}$ either equals $\emptyset$ or the closure of a common face $\Bar{F_{ij}}$.
\pause
\item An important subdivision is the equilateral one
\pause
\item The \textbf{mesh of a subdivision} is the diameter of its largest element
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is really the layout I wanted to obtain! Sadly your solution seem incompatible with the theme I am using though! I edited the question so now the file is runnable.Maybe I should change to a different package to insert images? Any advice? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid the incomatibility might come from the `enumitem` package, as beamer has its own management of lists, as far as I know. Simply it happened that with the default theme, I could use enumitem (but had to redefine the label from within it). I don't know  the inner details of beamer well enough to  change the right margin of its lists – that's why I tried with enumitem, which seems to take precedence in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your beamer theme is actually `Berkeley`, I'd suggest using two columns as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Simplicial Subdivisions}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Let $T=\sigma(x^0,...,x^n)$ be an n-simplex. A \textbf{simplicial subdivision} of T is a collection of (sub-) simplexes $\{T_i: i\in I\}$ such that $\bigcup_i T_i=\ \Bar{T}$ and $\forall i,j\ \Bar{T_j}\cap\Bar{T_j}$ either equals $\emptyset$ or the closure of a common face $\Bar{F_{ij}}$.
\pause
\item An important subdivision is the equilateral one 
\pause
\item The \textbf{mesh of a subdivision} is the diameter of its largest element
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{0.25\textwidth} \vspace*{\topsep}
    \onslide<1->
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{example-image}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```